# Remove transparency from Opera browser's tab bar

Tags: ubuntu, browser, opera, ubuntu-12.10

The last version of Opera 12.x have transparent tab bar. How can I make it non transparent? This is so annoying!

I use couple of browsers and when I open Opera I see the first browser's tabs :D

I looked at: `about:config`, Preferences, Appearance - no luck.

I used another Theme and it was working fine! However after I restart the browser it shows the transparent tab bar again.

I am on Linux (Ubuntu 12.10).

[image]

On the screenshot you can see that I see 4 other tabs from the other browser while I really have only "Speed Dial" tab opened.

In particular I am running version: 12.02 (I checked and it's the latest version of Opera)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the problem? Also, are you on 12.0x or 12.1x?

Comment: @andreasbovens done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor update to Opera 12.02 was released today with a fix for this

http://my.opera.com/ruario/blog/2012/10/02/problems-running-12-10-on-12-10